# find the indices to calculate the monthly averages of some hours in a time series

Tags: matlab, average

If I have one year worth of data

```
Jday = datenum('2010-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:...
    datenum('2010-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
dat = rand(length(Jday),1);
```

and would like to calculate the monthly averages of 'dat', I would use:

```
% monthly averages
dateV = datevec(Jday);
[~,~,b] = unique(dateV(:,1:2),'rows');
monthly_av = accumarray(b,dat,[],@nanmean);
```

I would, however, like to calculate the monthly averages for the points that occur during the day i.e. between hours 6 and 18, how can this be done?

I can isolate the hours I wish to use in the monthly averages:

```
idx = dateV(:,4) >= 6 & dateV(:,4) <= 18;
```

and can then change 'b' to include only these points by:

```
b(double(idx) == 0) = 0;
```

and then calculate the averages by

```
monthly_av_new = accumarray(b,dat,[],@nanmean);
```

but this doesn't work because accumarray can only work with positive integers thus I get an error

Error using accumarray
First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts.

What would be the best way of doing what I've outlined? Keep in mind that I do not want to alter the variable 'dat' when doing this i.e. remove some values from 'dat' prior to calculating the averages.

Thinking about it, would the best solution be

monthly_av = accumarray(b(idx),dat(idx),[],@nanmean);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. Just use logical indexing with `idx` in `b` and in `dat`:

```
monthly_av_new = accumarray(b(idx),dat(idx),[],@nanmean);
```

(and the line `b(double(idx) == 0) = 0;` is no longer needed).

This way, `b(idx)` contains only the indices corresponding to your desired hour interval, and `data(idx)` contains the corresponding values.

EDIT: Now I see you already found the solution! Yes, I think it's the best approach.